# hypothesis on bilinear form

Tags: matrices, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ an Hilbert space and $a:H\times H\to \mathbb{R}$ a bilinear form. Let $H_h\subset H$ a finite dimentional subspace and let $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ a basis of $H_h$.

What hypothesis must have on bilinear form such that the matrix $K=(a(w_i,w_j))_{i,j=1,\ldots,n}$ is an invertible matrix?

I think that $a$ must be symetric and positive definite.

Is this enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $K_{i,j}=a(w_i,w_j)_{i,j}$ is invertible if and only if the bilinear form $a$ is nondegenerate when restricted to $H_h \times H_h$. This means that the associated linear map $\tilde{a}: H_h \to H_h^*$ given by $\tilde{a}(x)=a(x,-):H_h \to \mathbf{R}$ is a linear isomorphism.

In particular, $a$ need not be symmetric. The field of symplectic linear algebra is all about vector spaces equipped with a nondegenerate *antisymmetric* bilinear form. Of course, if $a$ is symmetric and positive definite then it defines an inner product on $H_h$. The restricted bilinear form is non degenerate.

I might be a good idea to work this out in the case of the standard inner product on $\mathbf{R}^n$ for example. Hope this helps!